# Alternatives of UIDocumentPicker for ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, icloud

I used UIDocumentPicker to get documents from my iCloud account.Its working great in iOS 8 but its getting crashed in iOS 7.1.I know that it was introduced from iOS 8 but how to achieve this in iOS 7? Is there any alternative ways for it in iOS 7? I googled it but didn't find any solution to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iCloud drive is not available in iOS 7 nor is there a way to achieve this in iOS 7. As clearly state in the [`UIDocumentPickerViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocumentPickerViewController) is only available on iOS 8.

Comment: can we get folders in cloud without using cloud kit ? @rckoenes

Comment: No, Cloud Kit is also only available on iOS 8. iCould Drive is just not available on iOS 7 and since Apple does not support it you can not get it to work on iOS 7. You should just check the documentation because it is clearly stated that it only works on iOS 8.

Comment: Thnks for your comments @rckoenes ..Yes, I read the documentation its only supports for iOS 8.Could you tell me is there any other alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: There is not other way to achieve it, iCould drive is not available on iOS 7 or lower.

Comment: ok thanks once again.. Is there any way to stop including cloudkit framework in ios 7 ?

Comment: Yes check if the class/method are available. like `if ([UIDocumentPickerViewController Class]) ` where you know that `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is available.

Comment: ok @rckoenes..thanks for spending your valuable time for helping me.Thank you so much..